# How to clearInterval of the function that has started and running with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, react-native, setinterval, clearinterval

how to stop the loadFriendList when setWorker Value is"0"?

```js
const [worker, setWorker] = useState('1');
 
function start() {
 setInterval(loadFriendList,5000);
}
useEffect(start, []);
 
function n() {
  setWorker("0");
  Alert.alert('check', worker);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don't use strings as number it's an unnecessary hassle .

> use `useRef` hook to store intervalID .

This `useEffect` hook fires whenever worker is change.

> see inside the `[]` we've added worker variable. It's called dependancy array. Basically you're saying to useEffect look on these variables and fire if anything changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(worker == 0) intID.current && clearInterval(intId.current)
},[worker])
```

The `useRef` hook is holding on to the Interval you set up when page loading, to uniquely identify and run methods like `clearInterval()` in future

## Finally It Should Look Like

```
const [worker, setWorker] = useState(1);
const intId = useRef(null)
 
useEffect(() =>{
  intId.current = setInterval(loadFriendList,5000);
  return () => clearInterval(intId.current)
}, []);
 
useEffect(() => {
  if(worker == 0) intId.current && clearInterval(intId.current)
},[worker])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [worker, setWorker] = useState('1');
const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

function start() {
  setIntervalId(setInterval(loadFriendList, 5000));
}

useEffect(start, []);

function n() {
  setWorker("0");
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  Alert.alert('check', worker);
}
```